# php order by sequence multidimensional array in every fifth iteration

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sequence

I want to have an array that moves an index and value to the fifth count if it has a duplicate. And use the field value whether the value is an integer or alphanumeric.

Here is the idea:

```
<?php

$array  =  array(
                 array('value' => 1),
                 array('value' => **2**),
                 array('value' => **2**), //Move this
                 array('value' => **2**), //Move the also second duplicate
                 array('value' => A),
                 array('value' => B),
                 array('value' => C),
                 array('value' => 6),
                 array('value' => **7**),
                 array('value' => **7**), //Move this
                 array('value' => 8),
                 array('value' => 9),
                 array('value' => 10),
                 array('value' => 11)
                );
?>
```

I want to move the value 5 and 7 to every fifth iteration.

This must be the result.

```
<?php

$array  =  array(
                 array('value' => 1),
                 array('value' => **2**),
                 array('value' => A),
                 array('value' => B),
                 array('value' => C),
                 array('value' => **2**), //Move to fifth array, row
                 array('value' => 6),
                 array('value' => **7**),
                 array('value' => 8),
                 array('value' => **2**), //Move to the fifth array if has second duplicate
                 array('value' => 9),
                 array('value' => 10),
                 array('value' => **7**), //Move to fifth array, row
                 array('value' => 11)
                );
?>
```

I having trouble with this in weeks. Is there a possible code for this? Can anyone could help me?

Comment: Can you clarify more.

Comment: "I want to move the value 5 and 7 to every fifth iteration" What does that mean?

Comment: move a duplicate value to the fifth loop, row or iteration. example. 1. A, 2. A, 3. B, 4. C, 5. E, 6. F. I want to move the second A to the fifth count like 1. A, 2. B, 3. C, 4. E, 5. F. 6. A. hope you get it.

Comment: @JensonMJohn "The value 5 and 7 which has a duplicate will move for every fifth count, row, iteration"

Comment: I suggest trying to clean up that initial array, with a multi-dimensional array without keys and with the inner arrays all having the keys "value", that initial structure itself may be making things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @Kzqai I trying to fetch the data through a foreach loop. basically this is just the basic idea. Its come with a database not just an array hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've 100% understood the question, but the following code produces the required output:

```
$lastvalue= null;
$toinsert= null;
$insertcount= 0;
$insertindex= -1;
$result= array();

for($ndx=0;$ndx<count($array);$ndx++)
{
    $value= $array[$ndx]['value'];
    if ($value==$lastvalue) 
    {
        // It's a duplicate, set the insert index
        $insertindex= $ndx+4; // 4 places on from here (5 from the first occurrence)
        // Store the value we want to duplicate
        $toinsert= $array[$ndx];
        $insertcount++;
    }
    elseif(isset($toinsert) && $value==$toinsert['value']) {
        // We're already dealing with one of these, add this to the count to be
        // inserted
        $insertcount++;
    }
    else 
    {
        if ($ndx==$insertindex)
        {
            // We've reached the insertindex, insert our duplicate(s)
            for($i=0;$i<$insertcount;$i++)
            {
                $result[]= $toinsert;
            }
            $insertcount= 0;
        }
        $result[]= $array[$ndx];
        $lastvalue= $value; // Store this value so we can check for duplicates in the next iteration
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Essentially all I've done is iterate through the original array looking for a duplicate. If a duplicate is found it makes a note of the duplicate value and calculates the index where that value should be inserted (current index + 4 - which is 5 iterations from the original occurrence of the duplicate!). When it gets to that index it will insert the stored value into the result.

Note this won't work if you find a second set of duplicates before you find the insert point for the first (it'll abandon the first duplicates and work with the second). It also won't re-insert the duplicate if you reach the end of the original array before you get to the insert point.

Does that help at all?

**EDIT** Updated to be able to handle multiple consecutive duplicates. It's doing this by maintaining a count of how many records it needs to insert when it hits `$insertindex`.

NOTE: This code is getting a bit on ugly side now - it could well be one of the other answers already suggested adapts better to the multiple-duplicates scenario.

Comment: yes you did it man!!! thanks thanks. question what if i have triple duplicates i want to move both values with the same logic with this. the code you do remove the third duplicates. I want also to work with second duplicate or multiple

Comment: please see my updated question. i check the code but the second duplicate does not move to the fifth row

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will work for you. It looks for identical records and then moves them down to the correct place.

```
<?php

$array  =  array(
                 array('value' => 1),
                 array('value' => 2),
                 array('value' => 2),
                 array('value' => "A"),
                 array('value' => "B"),
                 array('value' => "C"),
                 array('value' => 6),
                 array('value' => 7),
                 array('value' => 7),
                 array('value' => 8),
                 array('value' => 9),
                 array('value' => 10),
                 array('value' => 11)
                );
function spaceIdenticalRecords(&$array){
        for ($i=1; $i < count($array); $i++) {//loop through the array
                if($array[$i]['value'] === $array[$i - 1]['value']){//look for records that match
                        $replace = array_merge(array_slice($array, ($i+1), 3),array($array[$i]));//move the mathing record down 4
                         array_splice($array, $i, 4, $replace);//place back in the array
                }
        }
}
spaceIdenticalRecords($array)
var_dump($array);
?>
```

EDIT:
This updated function should be able to handle any number of identical numbers.

```
function spaceIdenticalRecords(&$array){
        for ($i=1; $i < count($array); $i++) {//loop through the array


              if($array[$i]['value'] === $array[$i - 1]['value']){//look for records that match
                        for ($j= $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++){
                                if($array[$j] !== $array[$i]) break;
                        }


           if ($j+4 > count($array)){
                            $length = count($array) - $j -1;
                    }else{
                            $length = $j - $i + 2;
                    }

                    $replace = array_merge(array_slice($array, $j, 3),array($array[$i]));//move the mathing record down 4
                    for ($k = count($replace); count($replace) < $length +1; $k++){$replace = array_merge($replace,array($array[$i]));}
                    array_splice($array, $i, count($replace), $replace);//place back in the array
                    $i--; //don't miss records!
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works too but what if it has a second duplicate?

Comment: What do you mean by a second duplicate, can you post the sample array?

Comment: specifically, would you want AAABCDFRSDG to become
ABCDAAFRSD or
ABCDAFRSAD

Comment: not working it moves only the first duplicate but not the second duplicate. thanks

Comment: It does in my test, what is the test-array you're using?

Comment: same array @Taran Moltu

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution

```
<?php
$array  =  array(
                 array('value' => 1),
                 array('value' => 2),
                 array('value' => 2),
                 array('value' => "A"),
                 array('value' => "B"),
                 array('value' => "C"),
                 array('value' => 6),
                 array('value' => 7),
                 array('value' => 7),
                 array('value' => 8),
                 array('value' => 9),
                 array('value' => 10),
                 array('value' => 11)
                );

$required_array = array();
$temp = "";     
foreach($array as $key=>$child) {
    if($child["value"]==$temp) {
        $i = $key+4;
        $required_array[$i] = $child;
    } else {
        $i = $key;
        if(isset($required_array[$key])) $i++;

        $required_array[$i] = $child;   
    }
    $temp = $child["value"];
}
ksort($required_array);

print_r($required_array);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Following code should work for more than 2 duplicates

```
$required_array = array();
$temp = "";     
foreach($array as $key=>$child) {
    if($child["value"]==$temp) {
        $i = $key+4;
        $required_array[$i] = $child;
    } else {
        $i = $key;
        //if(isset($required_array[$i])) $i++; // Removed this line
        while(isset($required_array[$i])) { //added this line
            $i++;                           //added this line
        }                                   //added this line

        $required_array[$i] = $child;   
    }
    $temp = $child["value"];
}
ksort($required_array);

print_r($required_array);
```

Comment: yes it works also thanks for this but what if i have a multiple duplicate values? like array(array('value' => 2), array('value' => 2), array('value' => 2). how can the code move also the two values to the fifth row?

Comment: Answer edited, I want your feedback. Is it working as you required or not.